# What is the typical NVME SSD abrubt shutdown reaction time for a CC.SHN event until power loss?

Tags: pcie, ssd

The NVME standard under "7.6.2 Shutdown" defines the procedure for an abrupt shutdown event:

```
2. The host should set the Shutdown Notification (CC.SHN) field to 10b to indicate an abrupt 
shutdown operation. The controller indicates when shutdown processing is completed by 
updating the Shutdown Status (CSTS.SHST) field to 10b.
```

If I were to build a host application with an NVME drive installed and I detect a power loss, for how long would the host need to be able to supply the NVME drive after issuing CC.SHN to safely complete the abrupt shutdown?
Or in other words: How long does an SSD typically take to shut down and issue CSTS.SHST after receiving an abrupt shutdown condition on CC.SHN?

When I look at the datasheets of typical M.2 NVME SSDs they do not contain such low-level information. Are there any typical numbers?